# colorful screen issue when installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS via VirtualBox

Tags: 16.04, graphics, virtualbox

I see some strange coloured artifacts after installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox. How do I fix this problem?

[image: how to fix it? What to do?]

Comment: Did you install the virtual box graphics driver coming with the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)?

Answer (score 0):

Now, this question is a few months old now. But I had the same colourfull image show up when I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS in my virtualbox environment.
I had no clue how to fix it, so I started looking around on the big ol' internet.
No answer to be found anywhere.

So to answer this to all the noobs like me. This is caused by virtualization not being enabled in your BIOS. When that is enabled, it works without problems!

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu of the virtual-machine to insert Input/Keyboard/Insert Ctrl+Alt+Backspace.

This should bring you to the normal graphics mode.